# How to use method return from another Java class

Tags: java, class, extends, super

I have this method in a 'BankAccount.java' class

```
  public double calculateInterest()
  {
    double myInterest = 0.0;
    if(myBalance > 0.0){
    myInterest = this.myBalance * (myInterestRate/12.0);
  }
  return myInterest;
}
```

I need to use this method in my other class such as:

```
SavingsAccount extends BankAccount

      if(this.myBalance > 0)
      {  
          System.out.println(calculateInterest());
          this.myBalance += super.calculateInterest();
          this.myBalance -= this.myMonthlyServiceCharges;
      }
```

Why cannot I do

```
   this.myBalance += super.calculateInterest();
```

it is returning as 0.0

when it should be returning around 0.4

Any help would be great, thank you

it works if I put this code in my SavingsAccount class

```
public double calculateInterest()
{
  double myInterest = 0.0;
  if(myBalance > 0.0){
     myInterest = this.myBalance * (myInterestRate/12.0);
  }
  return myInterest;
  }
```

But it doesn't really teach me how to use the abstract class properly

Comment: is `myBalance` ever initialized higher than 0 ?

Comment: yes, if I remove the if statement, the statements below still do not work. Can post more code if it's unclear.

Comment: myBalance in BankAccount might be defaulted to 0 since u might not be initializing to any other value. It seems to be an instance variable of BankAccount class.

Comment: Please post both entire class so we can see what is happening.

Comment: if my logic for computing the interest in my SavingAccount class is correct, and I should use the super call, then my problem might be elsewhere?

Comment: what is the modifier used for your balance memebr variable in BankAccount, is it protected or not? And what is the package structure, is your base class and super claas is in same package or different ?

Comment: i think your Super class have balance member variable declared with default, and your base class is in different package. try making it as protected, then it will be accessible

Comment: In my above comments Child class typed as Base class and comments are now not editable.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  Here I reproduce with the following

```
public class BankAccount {

    protected double myBalance = 0;
    protected double myInterestRate = .6;

    public double calculateInterest() {
        double myInterest = 0.0;
        if (myBalance > 0.0) {
            double myInterestRate;
            myInterest = this.myBalance * (this.myInterestRate / 12.0);
        }
        return myInterest;
    }
}
```

And then....

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

    double myMonthlyServiceCharges = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount();
        sa.myBalance = 14;
        sa.doIt();
    }

    void doIt() {
        if (this.myBalance > 0) {
            System.out.println(super.calculateInterest());
            this.myBalance += super.calculateInterest();
            this.myBalance -= this.myMonthlyServiceCharges;
        }
    }

}
```

Can you try that and see if it works for you?